# Why should I click twice on Button to get data from useSWR ( NextJS )?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, use-swr

I have a `Button` component where I get data from my backend API using [useSWR.](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching)

This is my button:

```js
interface IButtonProps {
  address: string;
}

const AddressCheckButton = ({ address }: IButtonProps) => {
  const [shouldFetch, setShouldFetch] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const router = useRouter();
  const url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL;

  const { data: userLocation, error } = useSWR(
    shouldFetch ? url + address : null,
    (url) => fetcher(url, headers)
  );

  const handleValidate = () => {
    fetchData();
  };

  const fetchData = () => {
    try {
      setShouldFetch(true);
      if (userLocation) {
        const { zipCode, city, street, houseNumber } = userLocation;
        console.log(userLocation);

        if (zipCode && city && street && houseNumber) {
          dispatch(updateAddressId({ address }));
          dispatch(updateSolarLocation({ zipCode, city, street, houseNumber }));
          setShouldFetch(false);
          router.push(`/${address}`);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("error");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setShouldFetch(false);
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Button
        text="Code überprüfen"
        onClick={handleValidate}
        type={"ternary"}
      />
      {error?.length > 0 ? (
        <div className={styles.error}>
          <p>{error}</p>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};
```

The problem is when I click ( first click ) it logs an `error' because` userLocation`is`undefined `while the useSWR is fetching the data. The button code is synchronous and the useSWR is asynchronous, how to wait for`userLocation`to be available to run the`if` code?